# Formatting pgfplots bar graph with tabular* legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When I attempt to change the size of my bar chart so that it sits centered above my legend, I can't get the height and width to simultaneously fit my specifications. One dimension is always too small.

Ideally, the bar chart's width would match the width of the legend, the font size of the axis labels would match the font size of the legend, and the height of the bar chart would be much taller than it is now for easier readability.

I'm using     `\center` and     `\footnotesize` for both the chart and the legend, but they appear to be working slightly differently.

Any guidance is appreciated.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\center{Figure 1}
\pgfplotsset{
tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
label style={font=\footnotesize},
legend style={font=\footnotesize}
}
\begin{center}
    \resizebox{!}{0.2\linewidth}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[
            width=7cm,
            symbolic x coords={1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 
            25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48,},
            xtick=data,
            xlabel=Fama-French 48 Industry Code,
            ylabel=No. Observations,
            ytick={20,40,60,80},
            x=.5cm,
            ymin=0,
            enlarge x limits=0.02,
          ]
            \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
            (1,1)
(2,17)
(3,2)
(4,5)
(5,2)
(6,3)
(7,4)
(8,7)
(9,17)
(10,10)
(11,9)
(12,14)
(13,24)
(14,34)
(15,5)
(16,4)
(17,17)
(18,9)
(19,14)
(20,1)
(21,32)
(22,10)
(23,21)
(24,6)
(25,2)
(26,4)
(27,4)
(28,4)
(29,0)
(30,36)
(31,67)
(32,18)
(33,6)
(34,48)
(35,14)
(36,33)
(37,14)
(38,25)
(39,3)
(40,21)
(41,23)
(42,48)
(43,17)
(44,50)
(45,30)
(46,0)
(47,9)
(48,7)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}\end{center}

\footnotesize
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular*}
{\columnwidth}
{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
r@{\extracolsep{0in}}@{.}
l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
r@{\extracolsep{0in}}@{.}
l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
r@{\extracolsep{0in}}@{.}
l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
r@{\extracolsep{0in}}@{.}
l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
r@{\extracolsep{0in}}@{.}
l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
r@{\extracolsep{0in}}@{.}l}

\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Code} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Industry} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Code} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Industry} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Code} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Industry}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Agriculture} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{17} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Construction Materials} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{33} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Personal Services}\\


\multicolumn{2}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Food Products} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{18} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Construction} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{34} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Business Services}\\


\multicolumn{2}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Candy \& Soda} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{19} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Steel Works Etc} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{35} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Computers}\\


\multicolumn{2}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Beer \& Liquor} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{20} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Fabricated Products} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{36} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Electronic Equipment}\\


\multicolumn{2}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Tobacco Products} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{21} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Machinery} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{37} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Measuring \& Control Equipment}\\


\multicolumn{2}{c}{6} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Recreation} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{22} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Electrical Equipment} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{38} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Business Supplies}\\


\multicolumn{2}{c}{7} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Entertainment} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{23} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Automobiles \& Trucks} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{39} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Shipping Containers}\\


\multicolumn{2}{c}{8} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Printing \& Publishing} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{24} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Aircraft}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{40} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Transportation}\\


\multicolumn{2}{c}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Consumer Goods} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{25} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Shipbuilding, Railroad Eq.} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{41} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Wholesale}\\


\multicolumn{2}{c}{10} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Apparel} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{26} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Defense} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{42} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Retail}\\


\multicolumn{2}{c}{11} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Healthcare} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{27} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Precious Metals} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{43} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Restaurants, Hotels, Motels}\\


\multicolumn{2}{c}{12} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Medical Equipment} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{28} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Mining} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{44} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Banking}\\


\multicolumn{2}{c}{13} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Pharmaceutical Products} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{29} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Coal} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{45} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Insurance}\\


\multicolumn{2}{c}{14} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Chemicals} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{30} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Petroleum \& Natural Gas} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{46} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Real Estate}\\


\multicolumn{2}{c}{15} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Rubber \& Plastics} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{31} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Utilities} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{47} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Trading}\\


\multicolumn{2}{c}{16} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Textiles} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{32} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Communication} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{48} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Other}\\

\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}
Figure 1 provides descriptive statistics on adoptions by Fama-French 48 industry classification.
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First, your bar plot is wider than the margins.  Reset the width to \linewidth.

Comment: Thank you. I have replaced '\textwidth' with '\linewidth'.

Comment: @JohnKormylo As you can see, it fits on the page much better now, and it also resolves the centering issue. Please let me know if you have any suggestions for normalizing the font size between the bar chart and the legend.

Comment: I say do not use `\resizebox`. Simply change the bar width. Also if you want the font size in the plot to be larger than `\footnotesize`, you obviously have to use a different size. You can also define the x tick labels yourself via `xticklabels={1,,3,,5}` ... and so forth.

Comment: Actually, I meant \resizebox{\linewidth}{0.2\textwidth}{...}

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you for your comment - '\resizebox{\linewidth}{0.32\textwidth}' seems to do the trick.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.